# Alternative for multiple 'proxy' methods in Java

Tags: java, getter-setter, readability, proxy-classes, law-of-demeter

If I have 3 classes, let's for arguments sake call them:

- MainActivity
- GLRenderer
- OtherClass

Please Note that **GLRenderer** is not purely a proxy-class but does contain some proxy-methods.

The **MainActivity** initialises an int called *value*.  Now, if **OtherClass** needs to change that value for whatever reason and it only has direct access to the **GLRenderer** Class (which in turn has access to the **MainActivity** class, what is the best way to get access to this variable?

Currently, I'm using a setter method in **MainActivity**, and then using another setter in **GLRenderer** (a proxy method really, as it simply passes the value through).

This works fine and is how I'm doing things at the moment.  Here is some pseudo code (I realise this code may not compile, it's purely for the purpose of this question):

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private int value;

        public setValue(int valueToSet){

           value = valueToSet;

        }

}
```

**Second Class**

```
public class GLRenderer {

    private MainActivity activity;

        public GLRenderer(MainActivity activity){

            this.activity = activity;

        }


        public setValue(int value){

            activity.setValue(value);

        }

}
```

**Other Class**

```
public class OtherClass {

    private GLRenderer glRenderer;

        public OtherClass(){

            this.glRenderer = glRenderer;

        }

        public someMethod(){

            glRenderer.setValue(5);        

        }


}
```

Is the above better than doing something like this: (Please see comments in **OtherClass** code)

**GLRenderer**

```
public class GLRenderer {

    private MainActivity activity;

        public GLRenderer(MainActivity activity){

            this.activity = activity;

        }

    public MainActivity getActivity(){

        return activity;    

    }

}
```

**Other Class**

```
public class OtherClass {

    private GLRenderer glRenderer;

        public OtherClass(){

            this.glRenderer = glRenderer;

        }

        public someMethod(){

            //I know this is considered bad.....
            glrenderer.activity.setValue(5);

            //But how about this - is this any different/better and if so, why?
            glRenderer.getActivity().setValue(5);



        }


}
```

I know the first method requires a shorter final instruction in **OtherClass** but using the above method, I could access anything from **MainActivity** without having to effectively duplicate my getter/setters (which can be a pain if I have a lot of things that I need to access).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Is the above better than doing something like this?"

Yes, it is, because the second approach violates encapsulation by allowing OtherClass to know that GLRenderer is a proxy for MainActivity. It's none of OtherClass's business how the GLRenderer goes about setting its int value.

The first approach is also better from a maintenance perspective, because it allows MainActivity (and GLRenderer's usage of MainActivity) to change independently of OtherClass. In the second approach, a change to the way the int value is set would require OtherClass to change as well.